# Cannot scroll in the app first time touched

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

The ionic app is working for all the devices, but only in Ipad when we come to the screen the app is not scrolling

the thing we have done is we have to go to some other page in that app and come back to the old page, then the app is scrolling vertically. First time when app opens..it never scrolls. please help

```
<ion-content no-padding>
    <ion-list inset class="form-group required">
      <config-setting-form-section *ngIf="section" [section]="section"> 
      </config-setting-form-section>
      <div style="height:20px;"></div>
    </ion-list> 
</ion-content>
```

The thing is straight and clear, in all other devices its working fine.
Only in iPAD when we open the app the page comes it is not scroll-able, go to some other page within the app and come back to that old page.. scrolling is fine..

Comment: i had problems like this too only on ios devices. I don't know what causes this problem, but most of the time you can workaround with some css. For example try setting overflow to scroll or if the scroll container is rendered empty and then in a seperate paint the content (which causes the overflow) is rendered, try to set the height to cause initial overflow (101% or something like that).

Comment: FIxed: used pointer-events:auto in css. Also we have to use PointerEvents auto in media queries